# How to implement splash screen in app with TabActivity and MapActivity as default tab?

Tags: android, android-mapview, splash-screen, android-tabhost

I'm develing an app where are some tabs and in one of them (default one) is an `MapActivity`. My `MapActivity` got it's own `ProgressDialog` (it loads some stuff `onCreate`).

When I try to load another `ProgressDialog` in my main activity (`TabActivity`) the black screen shows up until map loads. Then `MapActivity`'s dialog shows and hides (after loading stuff) and then `TabActivity`'s dialog shows...

Note that im starting `TabActivity`'s dialog in `TabActivity.onCreate()` before calling intent with `MapActivity`.

Can anyone help me?

Code of my `TabActivity`:

```
public class MyTabActivity extends TabActivity {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private Handler progressDialogHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (null != progressDialog)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                prepareTabs();
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                progressDialogHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
            };
        }.execute();
    }

    private void prepareTabs() {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, MyMapActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(MyMapActivity.TAG).setIndicator(MyMapActivity.TAG).setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }
}
```

Error what I get (line with `tabHost.addTab(spec);`): `E/AndroidRuntime(8762)`, `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1`

And here is MyMapActivity:

```
public class MyMapAcitivity extends MapActivity {
    private MapView mapView;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private Handler progressDialogHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (null != progressDialog)
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate()");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_map_activity);

        loadMap();
        setupLocationBasedServices();
    }

    private void loadMap() {
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        loadEvents();
    }

    private void loadEvents() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyMapActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading events...");
        progressDialog.show();
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Event>>() {
            @Override
            protected ArrayList<Event> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                new EventLoader().loadEvents();
                progressDialogHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                return eventLoader.getEvents();
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could post some code marking where you see these behaviours,  but from what you have described, it sounds like the main thread is being blocked.  Try moving stuff that not essential for the UI to the background ([AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)).

UPDATE:

I think you should get rid f the progress dialog in your tab Activity.  I'll even backtrack here suggest to remove the AsyncTask (now that I can see what's going on).  Also, in the onCreate() in your TabActivity, remove the dialogs, this is probably causing the thread to block.

I think the only progress dialog should be `MyMapActivity.loadEvents()`.  I think the behaviour you describe is a bit ,complicated.  If this was me, I would trace this by hand, set through with the debugger to what gets called, when, and on which thread.  If I had my dev machine with I would try it out my self, but unfortunltely I don't.  I'll see if I can replicate your problem a little later.

Comment: @neciu Try making prepareTabs() synchronized.  It is likely is getting accessed by a different thread.

Comment: adding `synchronized` to the method definition didn't help.

Comment: "_So far I suppose, adding tabs should be done in UI Thread/ You cant do it in background tasks. You are adding all your tabs in DoInBackground method._" source: [link](http://www.techques.com/question/1-4426690/adding-tabbar-in-doInBackground-method-get-exception-in-android)

Comment: @neciu Thats absolutely right, anything that touches the UI has to be done on the main thread. Maybe you should look at your "MyMapActivity" and see what can be moved off the main thread there.  Posting that code also would help with a solutiion.

Comment: I've added MyMapActivity source.